# Microsoft Azure Mobile Service - Xamarin.Android Offline Sync Issues

Tags: c#, android, azure, xamarin, synchronization

I am trying to set up a Azure Mobile Service for an Android app. I started with the quick start samples that are given in Azure. I have created a database and server connection, hosted a Node.js back end, and setup the database with the tables I am trying to access successfully. I have followed the various tutorials that Microsoft has on the subject and I am still having trouble connecting to my database. After running my app a dialog box shows up with the message "Push operation has failed. See the PushResult for details". Here are the code snippets which I believe are required to access the database.

Initialization:

```
        //Mobile Service Client reference
    private MobileServiceClient client;

    //Mobile Service sync table used to access data
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<EmployeeItem> employeeSyncTable;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<EventItem> eventSyncTable;
    private IMobileServiceSyncTable<RecipientListItem> recipientListSyncTable;

    //Adapter to map the items list to the view
    private EmployeeItemAdapter employeeItemAdapter;
    private EventItemAdapter eventItemAdapter;
    private RecipientListItemAdapter recipientListItemAdapter;


    const string applicationURL = @"myurl(this is correct)";
    const string localDbFilename = "localstore.db";

    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);

        CurrentPlatform.Init();

        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
        // Mobile Service URL
        client = new MobileServiceClient(applicationURL, new NativeMessageHandler());
        await InitLocalStoreAsync();

        // Get the Mobile Service sync table instance to use
        employeeSyncTable = client.GetSyncTable<EmployeeItem>();
        eventSyncTable = client.GetSyncTable<EventItem>();
        recipientListSyncTable = client.GetSyncTable<RecipientListItem>();

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        employeeItemAdapter = new EmployeeItemAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Employee);
        eventItemAdapter = new EventItemAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.Event);
        recipientListItemAdapter = new RecipientListItemAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.RecipientList);

        //using this to test my connection
        await employeeSyncTable.InsertAsync(makeSampleEmployeeItem());
        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        OnRefreshItemsSelected();//calls SyncAsync() and RefreshItemsFromTableAsync() which updates views.

    }
```

From SyncAsync:

```
            await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();
            await employeeSyncTable.PullAsync("allEmployeeItems", employeeSyncTable.CreateQuery());
            await eventSyncTable.PullAsync("allEventItems", eventSyncTable.CreateQuery());
            await recipientListSyncTable.PullAsync("allRecipientListItems", recipientListSyncTable.CreateQuery());
```

Table Type Definition:

```
    public class EmployeeItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "EmployeeID")]
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Department")]
    public string Department { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "PrivledgeLevel")]
    public string PrivledgeLevel { get; set; }
}
```

So in summary. I create my mobile service client with my URL. Initialize the local store. Assign the sync tables to tables from the database. Then call SyncAsync(). This looks correct based on other samples I have seen. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "See the PushResult for details" - what does it tell you?

Comment: Where would I find the PushResult. Do I need to manually log it after a sync attempt? At the moment I am just catching any exceptions and outputting the message. After researching the PushResult, I read a thread that any error in the local store will cause the sync to fail. I will add a snippet of one of my table type definitions.

Comment: I assume PushResult is the return value of PushAsync().  I haven't used Azure services so I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the code below:

```
public async Task SyncAsync()
{
    ReadOnlyCollection<MobileServiceTableOperationError> syncErrors = null;

    try
    {
        await this.client.SyncContext.PushAsync();

        await this.todoTable.PullAsync(
            //The first parameter is a query name that is used internally by the client SDK to implement incremental sync.
            //Use a different query name for each unique query in your program
            "allTodoItems",
            this.todoTable.CreateQuery());
    }
    catch (MobileServicePushFailedException exc)
    {
        if (exc.PushResult != null)
        {
            syncErrors = exc.PushResult.Errors;
        }
    }

    // Simple error/conflict handling. A real application would handle the various errors like network conditions,
    // server conflicts and others via the IMobileServiceSyncHandler.
    if (syncErrors != null)
    {
        foreach (var error in syncErrors)
        {
            if (error.OperationKind == MobileServiceTableOperationKind.Update && error.Result != null)
            {
                //Update failed, reverting to server's copy.
                await error.CancelAndUpdateItemAsync(error.Result);
            }
            else
            {
                // Discard local change.
                await error.CancelAndDiscardItemAsync();
            }

            Debug.WriteLine(@"Error executing sync operation. Item: {0} ({1}). Operation discarded.", error.TableName, error.Item["id"]);
        }
    }
}
```

You can find the `PushResult` in the `syncErrors` list.